# How to make transparent screen on desktopApp in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make a window that's transparent and can see the back of the window.
I changed rgba of the canvas of BoxLayout but it has a black window yet.

python

```
from kivy.app import App

class textApp(App):
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    textApp().run()
```

kivy

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,0 #I changed here
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 

    Label:
        text: 'this is trancparent box'
        size_hint_y: 9 
    Label:
        text: 'this is comment box'
        size_hint_y: 1
        color: 0,0,1,1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vdyv.png)

Comment: Any window transparency must be handled at the window level and may be OS-dependent. I can't remember what SDL2 technically supports on different operating systems, but for the most part if it isn't in the Kivy Window API then it isn't actively supported.

Comment: oh...ok. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can make the kivy window transparent using `pywin32`, but it's worth considering that transparency will be given to the entire window, not the background.

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class AddWarning(FloatLayout):
    pass

class WarningApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.set_title("ht")
        HWND = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'ht')
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(HWND, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32gui.GetWindowLong(HWND, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(HWND, win32api.RGB(0,0,0), 230, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
        return AddWarning()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WarningApp().run()
```